# Search array formula returns too high a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I'm trying to count the number of times a certain due date is missed in a summary sheet on my workbook. On the parent sheet when something is overdue we label it as "LT". Something like this:
[image]
and we'd count it with:

```
=COUNTIF(CNs!AH:AH,"=LT")
```

However it started displaying zero no matter what, as you can see the true value is 8 so in trying to implement a solution, I wrote an array formula which is as follows:

```
{=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(LT,CNs!AH:AH)),1,0))}
```

The issue with my "fix" is that instead of zero it returns an exuberant figure:
[image]

Since I'm working with a text string I felt the array would be more reliable but at this point I just need the correct value to show up. I'd like to thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first formula should work. Regarding your fix, you should change to:

```
{=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("LT",CNs!AH:AH)),0,1))}
```

The 0 and 1 must be swapped for the sum to be correct.

Comment: I did try that but when swapping the 0 and 1 it also returns 0 in the sum

Comment: @IrvingLopez See edit. I forgot to put the quote around LT.

Comment: Even after adding the quotes, it's still 0

Comment: @IrvingLopez What is the result if you only do the sum for some cells and not the whole column? For example: {=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("LT",CNs!AH2:AH7)),0,1))}

Comment: Technically speaking AH2:AH7 is not the range (this sheet has a ton of entries) but interestingly if I go one by one it does count it if it has the LT condition ex. {=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("LT",CNs!AH16)),0,1))}

Comment: @IrvingLopez What is the result for a certain range (not the full column, nor a single cell)?

Comment: With any range the formula returns  0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132366/discussion-between-reddy-lutonadio-and-irving-lopez).